# Add two columns to a dataframe based on what value appears first

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, `df` :

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID6"
), val1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), sig1 = c(0.76, 0.15, 0.35, 0.66, 
0.7, 0.72), val2 = c(0.25, 0.81, 0.21, 0.06, 0.18, NA), sig2 = c(0.65, 
0.09, 0.55, 0.88, 0.09, NA), val3 = c(0.26, 0.24, 0.16, -0.1, 
0.22, NA), sig3 = c(0.64, 0.62, 0.65, 0.8, 0.04, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

> df
   ID val1 sig1 val2 sig2  val3 sig3
1 ID1    0 0.76 0.25 0.65  0.26 0.64
2 ID2    1 0.15 0.81 0.09  0.24 0.62
3 ID3    0 0.35 0.21 0.55  0.16 0.65
4 ID4    0 0.66 0.06 0.88 -0.10 0.80
5 ID5    0 0.70 0.18 0.09  0.22 0.04
6 ID6    0 0.72   NA   NA    NA   NA
```

This data frame contains 3 pairs of data for each ID number - `val1` and `sig1`, `val2` and `sig2` and `val3` and `sig3`.

I want to add an additional 2 columns.  I want the first column (`first_val`) to state the name of the first "`val`" column where the associated "`sig`" column is less than 0.5.  In the second column (`first_val_value`), I want to paste the associated `val1` or `val2` value for that ID.

## So for example -

For `ID1`, none of the `sig` values are less than 0.5, so the `first_val` column entry should be "-".

For `ID2`, `sig1` is less than 0.5, so the `first_val` column entry should be "val1".

For `ID3`, `sig1` is less than 0.5, so the `first_val` column entry should be "val1".

For `ID4`, none of the `sig` values are less than 0.5, so the `first_val` column entry should be "-".

For `ID5`, `sig2` is less than 0.5, so the `first_val` column entry should be "val2".

For `ID6`, none of the `sig` values are less than 0.5, so the `first_val` column entry should be "-".

So my desired dataframe would look like this:

```
> df
   ID val1 sig1 val2 sig2  val3 sig3 first_val first_val_value
1 ID1    0 0.76 0.25 0.65  0.26 0.64         -               -
2 ID2    1 0.15 0.81 0.09  0.24 0.62      val1               1
3 ID3    0 0.35 0.21 0.55  0.16 0.65      val1               0
4 ID4    0 0.66 0.06 0.88 -0.10 0.80         -               -
5 ID5    0 0.70 0.18 0.09  0.22 0.04      val2            0.18
6 ID6    0 0.72   NA   NA    NA   NA         -               -
```

What is the best way to construct this dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the data in long format, `filter` the values less than 0.5, keep only 1st row for each `ID` and join the data to get the original data back.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -ID, 
               names_to = c('.value', 'first_val'), 
               names_pattern = '([a-z]+)(\\d+)') %>%
  filter(sig < 0.5) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(1L) %>%
  mutate(first_val  = paste0('val', first_val)) %>%
  select(-sig) %>%
  right_join(df, by = 'ID')  %>%
  arrange(ID)
  

#  ID    first_val   val  val1  sig1  val2  sig2  val3  sig3
#  <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 ID1   NA        NA        0  0.76  0.25  0.65  0.26  0.64
#2 ID2   val1       1        1  0.15  0.81  0.09  0.24  0.62
#3 ID3   val1       0        0  0.35  0.21  0.55  0.16  0.65
#4 ID4   NA        NA        0  0.66  0.06  0.88 -0.1   0.8 
#5 ID5   val2       0.18     0  0.7   0.18  0.09  0.22  0.04
#6 ID6   NA        NA        0  0.72 NA    NA    NA    NA
```